# Why can't I declare my Class Object as such?

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I am currently creating a Class Object for a VBA file, its objective is to act as a range dictionary that can be passed single cells. If this cell is contained in one of the ranges, it returns the value associated to the corresponding range key. The class name is "rangeDic".

It is in the making so its functionalities are not implemented yet. Here's the code:

```
Private zone() As String
Private bounds() As String
Private link As Dictionary
Const ContextId = 33

'Init zone
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set link = New Dictionary
    ReDim zone(0)
    ReDim bounds(0)
    
End Sub

'properties
Property Get linkDico() As Dictionary
    Set linkDico = link
End Property

Property Set linkDico(d As Dictionary)
    Set link = d
End Property

Property Get pZone() As String()
    pZone = zone
End Property

Property Let pZone(a() As String)
    Let zone = a
End Property

'methods
Public Sub findBounds()

    Dim elmt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim temp() As String
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each elmt In zone
        ReDim Preserve bounds(i)
        temp = Split(elmt, ":")
        bounds(i - 1) = temp(0)
        bounds(i) = temp(1)
        i = i + 2
    Next elmt

End Sub
```

I was trying to instanciate it in a test sub in order to debug mid conception. Here's the code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rd As rangeDic
    Dim ran() As String
    Dim tabs() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    i = 1
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataRanges")
        While .Cells(i, 1).Value <> none
            ReDim Preserve ran(i - 1)
            ReDim Preserve tabs(i - 1)
            ran(i - 1) = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            tabs(i - 1) = .Cells(i, 3).Value
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End With
    
    Set rd = createRangeDic(ran, tabs)

End Sub

Public Function createRangeDic(zones() As String, vals() As Variant) As rangeDic

    Dim obje As Object
    Dim zonesL As Integer
    Dim valsL As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    zonesL = UBound(zones) - LBound(zones)
    valsL = UBound(vals) - LBound(vals)
    
    If zonesL <> valsL Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5, "", "The key and value arrays are not the same length.", "", ContextId
    End If
    
    Set obje = New rangeDic

    obje.pZone = zones()
    
    For i = 0 To 5
        obje.linkDico.add zones(i), vals(i)
    Next i
    
    Set createRangeDic = obje
End Function
```

Take a look at line 2 of `Public Function createRangeDic`. I have to declare my object as "Object", if I try declaring it as "rangeDic", Excel crashes at line `obje.pZone = zones()`. Upon looking in the Windows Event Log, I can see a "Error 1000" type of application unknown error resulting in the crash, with "VB7.DLL" being the faulty package.

Why so ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help

**Edit:** I work under Excel 2016

Comment: ` obje.pZone = zones()` seems weird to me. What happen if you remove the `()`?

Comment: @VincentG now that you say it it seems weird to me too, but it changes nothing. It works fine with "Object" (the property assignment works as well) and crashes with "rangeDic"

Comment: I suppose you have the necessary reference added. If so, please try changing all declaration type `As Dictionary` with `As Scripting.Dictionary`. If you have a reference to Word application, too, VBA my be confused...

Comment: Do you have the locals window or watch window open? Property procedures have really strict typing rules and can lead to crashes if the declared types don't match perfectly what the actual value is. Try swapping the property get to a function, and then the property let into a sub which assigns the private variable.

Comment: @FaneDuru the reference is there, I use Dictionaries in other parts of the code. Moreover the dictionary is filled correctly when the function doesn't crash Excel.

Comment: @Greedo I've had some "type mismatch" syntax errors because `zone` is a String array, but I thought I solved them. I'm going to give that a try !

Comment: @Greedo so switching to Sub and Function works, I can declare `obje` as `rangeDic`. I'd like to understand why doesn't it work with properties though...

Comment: I tested your code and it works as it is. I only changed the declarations as I suggested... What will cost you to try it? Press `Ctrl + H` and replace `dictionary` with `Scripting.dictionary`, at the class module level. I this way, VBA does not have  to guess what type a variable the declared Dictionary is...

Comment: @FaneDuru yep I just did that, and it still crashes. To replicate the crash, `Dim obje as Object` has to be replaced by `Dim obje as rangeDic`

Comment: I kept the declaration (in the function) `Dim obje As Object` and it works as it should. Since, a class is an object and then you "tell" to VBA what object are you referring to (`Set obje = New rangeDic`), it works. What Excel version do you use?

Comment: @FaneDuru i'm on Excel 2016. Yeah the declaration as Object is a workaround I found for my function to work, but I wanted to know why the declaration as `rangeDic` litteraly makes a fatal error in the VB7 dll.

Comment: I am afraid, I do not have another answer than "it shouldn't"... Excel is able to guess, for instance if you use `x = Range("A1:B4")`, even if it it should be `x = Range("A1:B4").value`, it knows returning an array, or `Set x = Range("A1:B4")` returns a range. Especially in a class module, the variables must be declared in a very clear way, to not oblige Excel guessing. According to the references you added, a specific variable type may be confusing for VBA.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am going to try that code on Excel from Office 365 at home, just to see if it is an issue with my Excel or just Excel 2016. I specifically declared everything as it should be I think, String arrays as String arrays and not as String, Dictionaries in an explicit way... Except an Excel fuck-up, I dont know either...

Comment: If you can live with Varaint then this should work : `Property Get pZone() As Variant` and `Property Let pZone(a As Variant)` and `Dim obje As rangeDic`. Maybe better would be to use `VBA.Collection` instead of arrays.

Comment: @DanielDušek to be fair I learned programming on Java, and I learned that types had to be declared precisely. That's why I'm not really fond of Variant type, even if sometimes VBA requires it (for each on arrays for example), I'll go on with the declaration as Object. I wanted to know why that happens and if it was a general issue, but maybe my Excel installation is just corrupted.

Comment: @MirageHF I wonder if you had the time to test the workaround I mentioned in my answer (to make a copy of the array before passing to the Let property).

Comment: @CristianBuse I thank you a lot for your answer, I was on business trip last week so I did not have the time to give it a try. I'll keep you posted, I will do it on monday !

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this is a bug. My Excel does not crash but I get an "Internal Error".

Let's clarify a few things first, since you're coming from a Java background.

**Arrays can only be passed by reference**

In VBA an array can only be passed by reference to another method (unless you wrap it in a Variant). So, this declaration:

```
Property Let pZone(a() As String) 'Implicit declaration
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
Property Let pZone(ByRef a() As String) 'Explicit declaration
```

and of course, this:

```
Public Function createRangeDic(zones() As String, vals() As Variant) As rangeDic
```

is the equivalent of this:

```
Public Function createRangeDic(ByRef zones() As String, ByRef vals() As Variant) As rangeDic
```

If you try to declare a method parameter like this: `ByVal a() As String` you will simply get a compile error.

**Arrays are copied when assigned**

Assuming two arrays called `a` and `b`, when doing something like `a = b` a copy of the `b` array is assigned to `a`. Let's test this. In a standard module drop this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ArrCopy()
    Dim a() As String
    Dim b() As String
    
    ReDim b(0 To 0)
    b(0) = 1
    
    a = b
    a(0) = 2
    
    Debug.Print "a(0) = " & a(0)
    Debug.Print "b(0) = " & b(0)
End Sub
```

After running `ArrCopy` my immediate window looks like this:
[image]

As shown, the contents of array `b` are not affected when changing array `a`.

**A property Let always receives it's parameters `ByVal` regardless of whether you specify `ByRef`**

Let's test this. Create a class called `Class1` and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Let SArray(ByRef arr() As String)
    arr(0) = 1
End Property

Public Function SArray2(ByRef arr() As String)
    arr(0) = 2
End Function
```

Now create a standard module and add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim c As New Class1
    Dim arr() As String: ReDim arr(0 To 0)
    
    arr(0) = 0
    Debug.Print arr(0) & " - value before passing to Let Property"
    c.SArray = arr
    Debug.Print arr(0) & " - value after passing to Let Property"
    
    arr(0) = 1
    Debug.Print arr(0) & " - value before passing to Function"
    c.SArray2 arr
    Debug.Print arr(0) & " - value after passing to Function"
End Sub
```

After running `Test`, my immediate window looks like this:
[image]

So, this simple test proves that the `Property Let` does a copy of the array even though arrays can only be passed `ByRef`.

**The bug**

Your original `ran` variable (`Sub test`) is passed `ByRef` to `createRangeDic` under a new name `zones` which is then passed `ByRef` again to `pZone` (the `Let` property). Under normal circumstances there should be no issue with passing an array `ByRef` as many times as you want but here it seems it is an issue because the `Property Let` is trying to make a copy.

Interestingly if we replace this (inside `createRangeDic`):

```
obje.pZone = zones()
```

with this:

```
Dim x() As String
x = zones
obje.pZone = x
```

the code runs with no issue even if `obje` is declared `As rangeDic`. This works because the `x` array is a copy of the `zones` array.

It looks that the `Property Let` cannot make a copy of an array that has been passed `ByRef` multiple times but it works perfectly fine if it was passed `ByRef` just once. Maybe because of the way stack frames are added in the call stack, there is a memory access issue but difficult to say. Regardless what the problem is, this seems to be a bug.

---

Unrelated to the question but I must add a few things:

1. Using `ReDim Preserve` in a loop is a bad idea because each time a new memory is allocated for a new (larger) array and each element is copied from the old array to the new array. This is very slow. Instead use a `Collection` as
   @DanielDušek suggested in the comments or minimize the number of `ReDim Preserve` calls (for example if you know how many values you will have then just dimension the array once at the beginning).
2. Reading a `Range` cell by cell is super slow. Read the whole `Range` into an array by using the [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) or [Range.Value2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2) property (I prefer the latter). Both methods returns an array as long as the range has more than 1 cell.
3. Never expose a private member object of a class if that object is responsible for the internal workings of the class. For example you should never expose the private collection inside a custom collection class because it breaks encapsulation. In your case the `linkDico` exposes the internal dictionary which can the be modified from outside the main class instance. Maybe it does not break anything in your particular example but just worth mentioning. On the other hand `Property Get pZone() As String()` is safe as this returns a copy of the internal array.
4. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of all your modules/classes to make sure you enforce proper variable declaration. Your code failed to compile for me because `none` does not exist in VBA unless you have it somewhere  else in your project. There were a few other issues that I found once I turned the option on.

Comment: Clear & comprehensive, also helpful in addition to the core issue - a real bundle of tips +:)